# How to deal with variable hash value

Tags: perl, perl-data-structures

I'm dealing with a SOAP API that can either return a hash or array of hashes depending if there is one or more records. This makes iterating over the return tricky. My current method is check the ref of return and either copy it to an array if it is an array, else push it on an array and then iterate over it.  Is there a cleaner idiom to use?

```
my @things;
if ( ref $result->{thingGroup} eq 'ARRAY' ) {
    @things = @{ $result->{thingGroup} };
} elsif ( ref $result->{thingGroup} eq 'HASH' ) {
    push @things, $result->{thingGroup};
} 

foreach my $thing (@things) { ... }
```

Comment: Are you using XML::Simple? If so, you should enable it's [:strict mode](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=218480). Also, [don't use XML::Simple](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=490846).

Comment: No, I'm using SOAP::Lite which looks to use XML::Parser under the hood.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Similar to @cjm's answer, but using the [ternary operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Conditional-Operator):

```
my $things = ref $result->{thingGroup} eq 'ARRAY'
    ? $result->{thingGroup}
    : [ $result->{thingGroup} ];
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use an array reference instead, which avoids an unnecessary copy:

```
my $things = $result->{thingGroup};
unless (ref $things eq 'ARRAY' ) {
    $things = [ $things ];
} 

foreach my $thing (@$things) { ... }
```

I removed the `elsif` because it's not clear that it adds anything.  If you want to ensure that a non-array is in fact a hash, then you should also have some code to handle the case where it isn't.